# Kotlin implement AES-CBC using built-in ECB Java implementation

Tags: java, kotlin, encryption, aes

I'm trying to implement AES-CBC cipher using built-in ECB Java implementation by following steps for CBC mode as specified [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography/block_cipher_modes_of_operation.htm). 
Note, I'm **not** concerned with the actual security (e.g., no padding, or using key as IV) of my implementation.

The problem is that only about some part of the bytes is encoded correctly when compared to this [site](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption) when using `PKCS5Padding`.

```
Key:              mvLBiZsiTbGwrfJB
Input:            abcdabcdabcdabcd

My result:        e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUi5F35z814ywucLJKKi4rTP8=
Result from site: e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUi9jNsRJtdELZliFtebuJrrc=


Key:              mvLBiZsiTbGwrfJB
Input:            abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd

My result:        e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUi5F35z814ywucLJKKi4rTP8=uf5VPLwumm+66ESiQMlKXJF35z814ywucLJKKi4rTP8=
Result from site: e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUi7I+cPTpraAgZIQvr8OLf7Iu4eKRG1MIcq5yQGsRt3PS
```

For `NoPadding` option:

```
Key:              mvLBiZsiTbGwrfJB
Input:            abcdabcdabcdabcd

My result:        e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUiw==


Key:              mvLBiZsiTbGwrfJB
Input:            abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd

My result:        e9qdKeY1m4OAIsPerfnUiw==uf5VPLwumm+66ESiQMlKXA==
```

Also, the decryption doesn't work at all, for `PKCS5Padding` I've got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.prepareInputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1005)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:848)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at AesEcb.decrypt(AesEcb.kt:27)
    at AesEcb.decryptToByteArray(AesEcb.kt:36)
    at AesCbcOwn.decrypt(AesCbcOwn.kt:32)
```

and for `NoPadding`:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 16 bytes
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1109)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at AesEcb.decrypt(AesEcb.kt:27)
    at AesEcb.decryptToByteArray(AesEcb.kt:36)
    at AesCbcOwn.decrypt(AesCbcOwn.kt:32)
```

I thought that these problems were related to padding options but I still can't make this work regardless of chosen option.

AES-ECB implementation which is used in CBC implementation:

```
object AesEcb : Aes {
    override val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")

    override fun encrypt(input: String, key: String): String {
        val encrypted: ByteArray = try {
            val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), "AES")

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
            cipher.doFinal(input.toByteArray())
        } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
            throw e
        }

        return Base64.getEncoder().run { encodeToString(encrypted) }
    }

    override fun decrypt(input: String, key: String): String {
        val output: ByteArray = try {
            val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), "AES")

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
            Base64.getDecoder().run { cipher.doFinal(decode(input)) }
        } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
            throw e
        }

        return String(output)
    }

    fun encryptToByteArray(bytes: ByteArray, key: String) = encrypt(String(bytes), key).toByteArray()
    fun decryptToByteArray(bytes: ByteArray, key: String) = decrypt(String(bytes), key).toByteArray()
}
```

My CBC implementation:

```
object AesCbcOwn {
    fun encrypt(plainText: String, key: String): String {
        val iv = key.take(16).toByteArray()
        val blocks = plainText.chunked(16).map { it.toByteArray() }

        val encryptedBytes = with(blocks.iterator()) {
            generateSequence(
                AesEcb.encryptToByteArray(iv xor next(), key)
            ) {
                try {
                    AesEcb.encryptToByteArray(it xor next(), key)
                } catch (e: NoSuchElementException) {
                    null
                }
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes.joinToString("") { String(it) }
    }

    fun decrypt(encryptedText: String, key: String): String {
        val iv = key.take(16).toByteArray()
        val encryptedBlocks = encryptedText.chunked(16).map { it.toByteArray() }

        val decryptedBytes = with(encryptedBlocks.iterator()) {
            generateSequence(
                AesEcb.decryptToByteArray(next(), key) xor iv
            ) {
                try {
                    AesEcb.decryptToByteArray(next(), key) xor it
                } catch (e: NoSuchElementException) {
                    null
                }
            }
        }

        return decryptedBytes.joinToString("") { String(it) }
    }

    private infix fun ByteArray.xor(other: ByteArray) =
        this.zip(other) { thisByte, otherByte -> thisByte xor otherByte }.toByteArray()
}
```

Comment: Your `AesEcb.encryptToByteArray()` method base64 encodes each block separately. This is unusual, you should encode all the blocks combined.

Comment: Both @t.m.adam and @Maarten Bodewes answers were correct - I've encoded all the blocks combined, changed ECB cipher to `NoPadding` and fixed issues with IV and it worked. I've also implemented PKCS5 padding for whole plaintext, instead of padding individual blocks.

Comment: Beyond algorithm: These types of runtime environments Java or Kotlin are not designed under security aspects and produce endless instances and copies on the heap. Presciently, you might consider lifecycle control of each sensitive entity, e.g. rather working with char[] than String-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECB method you've programmed performs padding. That should not be happening: the CBC plaintext needs to be padded, not the blocks fed to the AES cipher. Currently the ECB method returns two blocks instead of one.

The vector is not updated. The IV (**Initialization** Vector) is only XOR-ed with the initial plaintext block, after than the last ciphertext block needs to be XOR-ed with the next plaintext block. In other words, the ciphertext block becomes the *next* vector.